# Using LOOKUP with a string of more than 255 characters

Tags: excel, excel-2010, formula, lookup

In Excel 2010 I'm using =LOOKUP to place text in a cell dependent on the value of the cell being looked up. Short text strings work, but longer text strings cause a formula error. Here's the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(B58,{0,0;40,"TextA";100,"TextB";125,"TextC";145,"TextD";165,"TextE";200,""})
```

which works correctly and displays `TextA` or `TextB` etc. depending on the value in B58. However I want the LOOKUP to show a lot of text such as:

```
=LOOKUP(B58,{0,0;40,"Lots of text in here";100,"TextB";125,"TextC";145,"TextD";165,"TextE";200,""})
```

where the "Lots of text in here" is 432 characters, no punctuation but includes spaces.

So I don't really know, I'm assuming character limit.

Is there a way to adjust that LOOKUP so if the value is "whatever" it'll return text stored in a cell elsewhere on the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to place the lookup table itself in an area of cells in the sheet, or another worksheet.

Then your lookup formula can reference cells in the worksheet without the need for a large formula to be typed out.

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/lookup-function-HP010342671.aspx) for more info, specifically example 1.

It gives better control over your lookup list, and you can easily change this when required.

There is a restriction on the size of the formula text set at 8192 characters, as specified in the table [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, did some testing, it seems to be a 255 character limit...otherwise the formula works fine. Does anyone know if there's an easy way to replace "TextA" with code that allows it to look and retrieve text of over 255 characters from a named cell?

Comment: That's weird. I wasn't aware of a 255 character limit - seems strange to me. But it's good to know. I wonder if the same applies even if you put it as a cell based lookup.

Comment: It's definitely strange, unless I'm not understanding a term somewhere in that table of size restrictions, the 255 character limit isn't mentioned anywhere. At least I know that it's not my lookup that's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Excel does have a warning (and, for a change, helpful advice!):

[image: SO243888368 example]

Instead of `"Lots of text in here"` something like `"Lots of text"&" in here"` with the `&` around the half-way mark should serve.